# TeamCity server url from build script

Tags: teamcity

I heed to use TC API from build script (gradle). I can read user name and password, from project properties, but I have to read serverUrl as well. But I did not find property `teamcity.serverUrl` described in doc ([right there](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-RESTAuthentication))

May be this property is missed only on our build TC server?

Comment: how exactly did you check for `teamcity.serverUrl` property?

Comment: from my groovy plugin, something like `project.teamcity["teamcity.serverUrl"]`

Answer (score 1):

This very parameter is a *configuration parameter* 
Such parameters can be used in web UI, but are not implicitly passed to Gradle build

In your case, use **Additional Gradle Command Line Parameters** field in build step configuration and add following flag:

```
-PserverUrl=%teamcity.serverUrl%
```

This will pass the value explicitly. You can access server url in gradle like this:

```
println("Server url is $project.serverUrl")
```

**UPD**

If customising paramteres is not an option, you can use another way. There is a system property `teamcity.configuration.properties.file` that contains path to a file, that contains all the *configuration parameteres*  in usual properties format. So, inside Gradle do something like:

```
def configFilePath = project["teamcity.configuration.properties.file"]
def props = new Properties();
props.load(new File(configFilePath).newDataInputStream())
def serverUrl = props["teamcity.serverUrl"]
```

Comment: Actually, the end goal I try to reach is to avoid any additional manipulation for user of my plugin, which uses TC API. In way you told me it leads to additional action for user.

Comment: You never mentioned you are implementing a Gradle plugin.

Comment: Yep, it've already got it, but you right. This is one of correct ways to achieve it.